# JSON objects from URL connection displayed in tableview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetch loans from internet

-(void)loadData
{
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                          @"http://192.168.1.104:8080/Test/ItemGroup.jsp"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [connection release];
    self.responseData = nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Process loan data
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.responseData = nil;


    array=[responseString JSONValue];
    NSMutableString *text=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Values:\n"];
    for (int i=0; i <[array count]; i++) {
        [text appendFormat:@"%@\n",[array objectAtIndex:i]];

        // NSLog(@"Values:""%@\n",array);

    }

}
```

Comment: Tushar, I know this is your first question, don't put entire question in title. Just give a small title , and post a description of the question you have, and only post specific code that relates to the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) (a Cocoa RESTful web services framework) to fetch the data and use the [object mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) feature to map returned data to an array of objects.

The example given in the RESTKit Object Mapping  wiki maps a JSON doc into an array of Article instances: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping